# Advanced SQL SERVER 2008 videos

Tags: sql-server-2008

Where do I find advanced SQL SERVER 2008 videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few SS2k8 videos [here](http://www.sqlservervideos.com/browse/skill/), otherwise a google search will probably turn up what you are looking for, if it's available.

Answer (score 1):

A couple places come to mind:

1)  PASS (Professional Organization for SQL Server) has a yearly conference with the best content you can get on SQL Server.  You have to register (for free), but you can watch old recorded sessions there.
http://www.sqlpass.org/LearningCenter/SummitOnDemand.aspx

2)  Microsoft does free SQL 08 webcasts from some of the best SQL trainers (like Kim Tripp).  You need a Windows Live account:
http://www.microsoft.com/events/series/technetsqlserver2008.aspx?tab=webcasts&id=42572

Those are 2 places I would go for webcasts.